# Xcode Utility Application - Flipsideview call table reloaddata

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using the standard apple Utility Application template.

In the FlipSideViewController.m I need to reload the data in the table.

I have tried

```
 [self.tableView    reloadData];
```

and

```
 [self.view.tableView   reloadData];
```

but neither compile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.\Thanks

Comment: Did you add a tableView to the FlipSideViewController?

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is a `UITableViewController` then `[self.tableView reloadData]` should do it. If you have a viewController then call `[/*self*/yourTableViewOutletName reloadData]; the`self` is optional there.